# Pytorch is throwing an error RuntimeError: result type Float can't be cast to the desired output type Long

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, torch

How should I get rid of the following error?

```
>>> t = torch.tensor([[1, 0, 1, 1]]).T
>>> p = torch.rand(4,1)
>>> torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()(p, t)
```

The above code is throwing the following error:

**RuntimeError: result type Float can't be cast to the desired output type Long**

Comment: The first tensor must be converted to float `t = torch.tensor([[1., 0., 1., 1.]]).T`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BCEWithLogitsLoss` requires its target to be a `float` tensor, not `long`. So you should specify the type of `t` tensor by `dtype=torch.float32`:

```py
import torch

t = torch.tensor([[1, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=torch.float32).T
p = torch.rand(4,1)
loss_fn = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

print(loss_fn(p, t))
```

Output:

```
tensor(0.5207)
```